# Java API for composing regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I am writing an application that needs to define and compile patterns at runtime. Using the Java `Pattern` API, I need to pass a string and get a pattern. Something like this:

```
Pattern.compile("ab*|c*");
```

The problem is that my patterns are modular and I would like to compose them using alternative, kleene star, etc, for example:

```
Char a = new Char('a');
Char b = new Char('b');
Char c = new Char('c');
Regex r = new Regex(new Alt(new Seq(a, new KleeneStar(b)), new KleeneStar(c)));
Pattern.compile(r);
```

I haven't found an API in JDK to allow me such a thing. I assume that the underlying
implementation of pattern should have such an API. Does any one know how I can get such an API from
the standard Java, or are there third party libraries for that?

In the end, I think I can create such an API myself with some recursive visitors to printout
the string, but would be nice if it already exits.

Comment: You might want to browse the [`java.util.regex.Pattern` source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#Pattern).

Comment: I don't quite understand your example, am I confused; `Regex`, `Alt`, and `Seq`, are not native objects, right?  What is the difference in you defining your `Regex` vs. a `a + "" + b + "*" + "|" + c + "*"`?

Comment: I think semantically they are equivalent: you can compose parts of a pattern using string as you mentioned. But I sort of feel more comfortable if I can compose them via an API as it's safer. I don't need to care about escapes, etc.

Comment: I would think you'd have to build an API then (sort of).  It should probably be one class which either extends `Pattern` or returns `Pattern` objects.  Something like `PatternBuilder` where you can call methods like `addStringSeq`, `addWhiteSpace`, `addKleeneStar()`, etc.  You could overload things like `addKleeneStar()` with characters and strings (for instance if it's just a character just add `c + "*"`, if it's a string add `"(" + str + ")*"`.

Comment: But note that if you do this, you'll have to escape characters...if I call `addKleeneStar("abc*")` (or `new KleeneStar(...)` as you suggested), I really mean the literal string for `Pattern` should be `"(abc\\*)*"`

Comment: With all due respect... why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? Building a RegEx engine is pretty hard.

Comment: @EddieB I just want the API to compose patterns, and then let the Java regex engine do the job for me. I don't want to rewrite parts `compile` and `match`. With the current API, I can only get a pattern for a full string and then run it, so composition of patterns is difficult. (or at least there is no API support for composition)

Comment: Take a look at the 'Greedy' quantifiers in the Pattern.java source ~ ln 3033 in JDK 7 Pattern.java for the closure method...

Comment: @Ali Example source from the JDK https://gist.github.com/EdwardBeckett/fab9b00a92a8df48ec18

Comment: @EddieB I'm sure implementing pattern matching is difficult, that's why I don't want to to that. I was wondering if I can define the pattern using a Java API, rather than String. A very straightforward implementation would be to create such hierarchy, and then to a toString to get the pattern and then compile it using the Java API.

Comment: Well... you could make a custom RegEx char class, (enum, map, etc) to use as a private member to your implementation...

Comment: @Ali Railo is an opensource version of ColdFusion built in Java and they have a RegEx implementation you 'might' be able to get some use from... 

https://gist.github.com/EdwardBeckett/76e1211a336c10aa545b

Comment: @Ali ... Apache Commons StringUtils should have a great example... http://bit.ly/1zPtUs1

Answer (score 1):

Try http://itsallbinary.com/project-simply-regex/

https://github.com/itsallbinary/simply-regex

Code examples:

```
String builtRegex = SimpleRegex.regex().startingWith().exactString("abc")
                                       .then().oneOfTheCharacters('d', 'e', 'f')
                                       .build();

SimpleRegex.regex().anywhereInText().oneOrMoreOf('a').build();

String builtRegex = SimpleRegex.regex().anywhereInText().oneOrMoreOf(groupHaving().exactString("abc").then().anyDigitChar().build())
                       .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

[VerbalExpressions](https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/JavaVerbalExpressions) looks like what you're describing. `ab*|c*` would be expressed as something like that:

```
VerbalExpression.regex()
        .then("a").then("b").zeroOrMore()
        .or("c").zeroOrMore()
        .build()
```

It also exists [in different languages](http://verbalexpressions.github.io/).

Comment: I don't like the look of this. Because the parse tree of the `VerbalExpression` differs from that of the regex. For instance, `VerbalExpression.regex().then("a").then("b")` is an object which corresponds to `a"`, which isn't even a subexpression (`*` has higher precedence than concatenation). Conversely, no subterm of the java snippet corresponds to the subexpression `b*`. I can't help feeling that whoever wrote this module doesn't quite understand why using `new Pattern(regex)` might be undesirable. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Pattern.compile(regex)`, not `new Pattern(regex)`.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it tries too much to be fluent, and doing so loses some of the semantics of the regex. It works well for short and simple regexes, but then get more complex quickly (e.g. the syntax for captures)... It answers the question, though :)